Is Arqade's 8-bit theme lost forever?
Spoiler alert: Nostalgia ahead.
I get that every site had its theme standardized few years ago, but I really loved the 8-bit style we used to have for fonts, buttons and labels.
Is there any way to bring something of our old look back and be a little more "original"? The only customizable elements left for a community are the header (mothership <3), the footer, and the badges.
I know that there's probably nothing we can do about it, but it would be great to have.
Edit: Here's an old 8-bit mockup (designed by Jin), for reference:


Tagged with [tag:feature-request] so it'll be on the radar of the company, not that I think it'll make a difference... but you're not the first to express nostalgia for the old design.

@Wipqozn thank you anyway for the support!

There's a post on Meta SE about theme standardisation - we were lucky to even keep the badge design let alone the fonts etc :(

@Robotnik badges and upvote/downvote buttons should be customizable for every site, come on... We had a beautiful site before that, it's just not fair.

Left Nav, Responsive Design, and Theming next steps - has answers for and a summary of (and links to) the previous talking points when standardised theming was announced (ie the "Response to Feedback" section of the question post). Also RE: Fonts - we might be able to argue for a return to Tempesta - at least in some spots?

@Robotnik that will be a good compromise to me

Why Tempesta, particularly? It doesn't look like the most user-friendly version of a monospace font.

@Joachim Tempesta was the font used for question headers (and a few other places) before the SE theming standardisation. I raised it given the crux of this question is a "return" to the more customised theme of Arqade. That doesn't mean we can't look at other options as well :)

Related - Can We Use the Old Chat Theme?

I personally would love a return to the old theme. I joined after the theme was standardised, so I've never seen it, but it looks amazing. Also, I don't see the need for all communities to look exactly the same as each other when we're not the same. It's (the 8-bit look) also pretty representative of video games.

If we got some stuff back... it'd be nice to have the red glowing heart back in a more prominent location.

A lot of the changes probably have to do with meeting certain Accessibility guidelines/laws, so it will probably not be possible to bring something like this back.  Someone who's really clever might be able to create a user script one can use to restore a lot of the theming, but that would be a pretty good effort I feel like.

@TimmyJim I understand accessibility guidelines, but if Stackoverflow can switch between light/dark theme, devs could add a sort of toggle for new/old design here. It's just a matter of CSS.

@pinckerman SE has said though that creating a dark mode for every site is far down on their list of priorities, because they'd have to create a new stylesheet for every site, customized to every site (if they want it to look good). A toggle would be good preference-wise and accessibility-wise, though it might make it an even lower priority.

@DaemonsMercy I don't mind a dark theme for every site (which would be cool, btw), I'm just suggesting to bring back a customized font and a couple of buttons.

@pinckerman Oh, ok. I thought you wanted to bring back everything (which I also support), not a few buttons/font. That's much more manageable.

@DaemonsMercy yeah to be honest I'd like the whole nostalgic look and feel :D but I'm aiming to a reasonable goal, at least...

For reference, here's a 2015 snapshot of the mockup's question in the image with the old style:

